# Why is Luke not hitting back Emil Pangborn in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, city-of-bones

In The Mortal Instruments: City of Bones (2013), Luke is a werewolf and has enough power to break the braces which are around in his hands in this scene and can hit back Emil Pangborn. But he didn't. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He simply can't. Keep in mind that they know he's a werewolf, so it make sense that they handcuffed him with strong braces he can't break. And as far as I remember he tried to do so more than once but couldn't, even when he was tortured and later when he was fighting them (so he was really unable to break them and not faking).